# Including files from different folders include ("./".$_GET['id'].".php");

Tags: php

hi everybody just found this code

```
<?PHP
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    if (!empty($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] != "index") {
        if (file_exists($_GET['id'].".php")) {
            include ("./".$_GET['id'].".php");
        } else {
            echo "Not Found section";
        }
    } else {
        include ("start.php");
    }
} else {
    include ("start.php");
} ?>

<a href="index.php?id=gallery">Gallery</a>
```

i want use it , but i have my files in another folder: "FILESPHP", how i can make link to FILESPHP folder? .. thankyou.

Comment: This is a terrible idea. A user could maliciously include any PHP file on your filesystem.

Comment: how is secure idea? .. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Consider using google before.

- with [`getcwd()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) you get your current directory
- you can navigate from there as in every linux

Kind of:

```
<?PHP
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    if (!empty($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] != "index") {
        if (file_exists($_GET['id'].".php")) {
            include ("./FILESPHP/".$_GET['id'].".php");
        } else {
            echo "Not Found section";
        }
    } else {
        include ("FILESPHP/start.php");
    }
} else {
    include ("FILESPHP/start.php");
} ?>
```

Comment: @Rick Please have a look at the [tour].

Comment: Probably you want to update the file_exists part too with the FILESPHP path

Answer (score 0):

thank you inetphantom,

when refresh page.. `FILESPHP/start.php`  load very GOOD..

but.. when i call files in FILESPHP.. not works..

the example is: `<a href="index.php?id=gallery">Gallery</a>` show "Not Found section"

Comment: You should probably be making a comment on @inetphantom's answer, not making a new answer. Try the `add a comment`-button under the answer :)